# Solve $\frac{f'(x)f'''(x)}{(f''(x))^2}=C$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, functions, derivatives

Let $f$ be twice differentiable almost everywhere and continuous. $C$ is a constant.

Solve for the following differential equation:

$\frac{f'(x)f'''(x)}{(f''(x))^2}=C$ almost everywhere.

If we remove the "almost everywhere", the solution is pretty standard:

$f$ can be a log function, exponential function, or polynom. To be more specific, when $C=1$, it seems that $f(x)=ae^{bx}+c$ where $a,b,c$ are constants. When $C=2$, $f(x)=a\ln(x+b)+c$. When $c\neq 1$ or $2$, $f(x)=a(x+b)^c+d$

**Can we get more solutions if we add back the "almost everywhere"?**

Comment: You start by stating that $u$ is a twice differentiable function, then never use $u$.  What is $f$?

Comment: And if $u$ is $f,$ you’ve taken the third derivative of $f,$ but only asserted $u$ is twice differential equations.

Comment: Well, since the formula applies pointwise, it seems we could stitch together multiple solutions so that the result is continuous...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Updated answer after the OP changed the wording of his question.
$$\frac{f'(x)f'''(x)}{(f''(x))^2}=C$$
$y(x)=f'(x)$
$$\frac{y''}{y'}=C\frac{y'}{y}$$
$$\ln|y'|=C\ln|y[+\text{constant}$$
$$y'=c_1y^C$$
$$\frac{y'}{y^C}=c_1$$
$$\frac{y^{1-C}}{1-C}=c_1x+c_2\quad\text{in case of}\quad C\neq 1$$
$$y=(1-C)(c_1x+c_2)^{1/(1-C)}=f'$$
$$f(x)=\frac{(1-C)^2}{2-C}(c_1x+c_2)^{(2-C)/(1-C)}+c_3\qquad 
\begin{cases}
C\neq 0 \\
C\neq 1 \\
C\neq 2 
\end{cases}$$

or equivalently
$$f(x)=(ax+b)^{(2-C)/(1-C)}+c \qquad 
\begin{cases}
C\neq 0 \\
C\neq 1 \\
C\neq 2 
\end{cases}
\tag 1$$
$$f(x)=ax^2+bx+c \qquad C=0 \tag 2$$
You correctly found the solutions in the cases $C=1$ and $C=2$.
$$f(x)=ae^{bx}+c \qquad C=1 \tag 3$$
$$f(x)=a\ln(x+b)+c\qquad C=2 \tag 4$$
with $a\neq 0$ in all cases so that $f''(x)\neq 0$.

All above holds if $f(x),f'(x),f''(x)$ are differentiable everywhere.

If it is not the case this supposes that the PDE is not valid is some particular points but valid almost everywhere.  Then they are an infinity of continuous piecewise solutions : On each segment between those particular points $f'(x),f''(x),f'''(x)$ exist and $f(x)$ complies to the above equations $(1)$ or $(2)$ or $(3)$ or $(4)$. Two of the parameters can be determined so that there is no discontinuity between adjacent segments. So they are an infinity of continuous piecewise solutions

If no additional condition is specified at each particular point, the third parameter remains arbitrary and $f(x)$ is likely to be multivalued that is with different branches

Comment: This is fine if the equalities hold everywhere. But what if the initial equality only holds a.e.?

Comment: Of course if $f''(x)$ is not differentiable in some particular points they are an infinity of continuous piecewise solutions. On each segment between those points $f''(x)$ is differentiable and $f(x)$ complies to the above equation. Two of the parameters are determined so that there is no discontinuity between adjacent segments. If no additional condition is specified at each point, the third parameter remains arbitrary and $f(x)$ is likely to be multivalued that is with different branches.

Comment: when $C=1$, it seems that $f(x)=ae^{bx}+c$ where $a,b,c$ are constants.

Comment: Correct. And same comment about the piecewise solutions.

Comment: I am not sure why "two of the parameters" are determined such that the function is continuous. To me, in the 1-D case, we just need to adjust the small "c" in each solution to make the point-wise combination continuous. Not sure if I am right. In the multi-variate case as you commented, it will be more complicated because I am not sure if we can make the whole boundary hypersurface continuous just be adjusting the parameters

Comment: All depends on what we want. If we want each segment starts at a given point $(x_1,y_1)$ and ends at another given point $(x_2,y_2)$ is is easy to determine the parameters $a$ and $c$ for this segment and with arbitrary $b$. Similarly for the next segment from  $(x_2,y_2)$ to  $(x_3,y_3)$ with different (or not) $b$. And so on.

Comment: Hi Jacquelin, I think there is a typo: "$y(x)$" in the (1),(2),(3),(4) should be "$f(x)$"?

Comment: @High GPA. $y(x)\neq f(x)$ since $y(x)=f'(x)$  by definition.

Comment: @JJacquelin Are you sure? we also have $$f(x)=\frac{(1-C)^2}{2-C}(c_1x+c_2)^{(2-C)/(1-C)}+c_3\qquad 
\begin{cases}
C\neq 0 \\
C\neq 1 \\
C\neq 2 
\end{cases}$$ right above the Eqn (1); I think that statement is equivalent to Eqn(1). Eqn (1) says: $$y(x)=(ax+b)^{(2-C)/(1-C)}+c \qquad 
\begin{cases}
C\neq 0 \\
C\neq 1 \\
C\neq 2 
\end{cases}
\tag 1$$

Comment: I think Eqn (1) should be: $$f(x)=(ax+b)^{(2-C)/(1-C)}+c \qquad 
\begin{cases}
C\neq 0 \\
C\neq 1 \\
C\neq 2 
\end{cases}
\tag 1$$

Comment: @High GPA. You are right there is a confusion of notation in Eqs. (1-4). Now fixed. Of course $y(x)\neq f(x)$ : the exponents are different. Thank you for the observation.