# A simple difference equation or functional equation that has a solution $(ax+b)^c$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, functional-equations

I am looking for a (system of) functional equation or difference equation that has a solution: $f(x)=(ax+b)^c$, where $a,b,c$ are constants. Constant $a,b,c$ cannot appear in the equation.

For example, the closest possible equation I found is a [differential equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3257782/solve-fracfxfxfx2-c): $\frac{f'''f'}{(f'')^2}=C$.

For another example, consider a special case. The simple function $g(x)=x^c$ is the unique solution to a very simple functional equation: $g(xy)=g(x)g(y)$. However, a differential equation is considerably more complicated. The motivation of this question is to find an elegant functional equation that has the same solution as a more complicated differential equation.

Answer (score 1):

Why, you just have to differentiate away all three constants to end up with a third degree equation:
$$\left({f\cdot f''\over(f')^2}\right)'=0$$

Comment: Three degrees sound too complicated. I am trying to find a first degree or zeroth degree (hopefully) equation.

Comment: A first degree equation would give you one constant. There is no going around it. (That is, if we are talking about differential equations.)

Comment: Ah good point! I think your statement is correct for classic first order ODE in the form of $F(t,f,f')=0$.  Consider a very simple first order differential equation: $f'(x+y)=f‘(x)+f'(y)$. The continuous solution is $f'(x)=cx$ and therefore $f(x)=ax^2+b$. Two constants magically appear!

Comment: My statement is correct for classic _any_ order ODE: first order means one constant, third order means three. This does not apply to functional or mixed (functional-differential) equations, though. Also, functional equations don't really have the concept of order or any general theory, for that matter. With them, every kind of weirdness is possible.

Answer (score 0):

$$f’(x)=c(ax+b)^{c-1}a=ac\dfrac{f(x)}{ax+b}$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is a very good direction that I can further try. Note that 1) this is a differential equation. 2) in a differential equation, the constants, $c_1, c_2, c_3$, are usually "solved out", rather than pre-defined in the equation. Here the constants are $a,b,c$.